# how can I merge 2 or more patern in preg_match?

Tags: php, preg-match

hi there how can I merg 2 or more in preg_match?

for example:

```
1: /^([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}| |\x{200C}])+$/
2: A-Z a-z
3: 1-9
4: ۱-۹
```

1+2->?

1+2+3+4?

Edit:

for example I want do it something like this:

```
if(preg_match(A-Z) OR preg_match(1-9))
   echo 'string is number or alphabet or both';
else
  echo 'wrong string';
```

Comment: Sorry, it is completely unclear what you ask. What do you mean by "merge 2 or more"? 2 or more _what_?

Comment: for example: `if(preg_match(/^([\x{0600}-\x{06FF}| |\x{200C}])+$/) AND  preg_match(a-zA-z))`

Comment: Sorry, a question should be readable, understandable and make sense to be answered. Don't have us drag out details from you, don't add important details to comments. There is an `edit` button below your question. _Use it_. Try to think from our point of view: we have no clue what you are talking about, you have to explain it to us. It is _you_ who wants something from us. So it is in your interest to make things easy for us. Do not set up a _guessing game_ here. Thanks.

Comment: @arkascha thanks for your note. ok I do it.

Comment: Why not use `if (preg_match($regex1, $str) || preg_match($regex2, $str)) { echo "something was found (though not clear what ;-))"; }` This is calling `preg_match()` for each regular expression individually.

Comment: 1. regular expresions do define an `OR` operator, it is documented and 2. you should read about the `/u` modifier for the preg functions which enables unicode more. Also clearly stated in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure I understand your needs but it seems to me that you want to use [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
/^(?=.*[\x{0600}-\x{06FF} \x{200C}])(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[1-9])(?=.*[۱-۹])/
```

where

`(?=.*[\x{0600}-\x{06FF} \x{200C}])` make sure we have at least one character in range
`(?=.*[a-zA-Z])` make sure we have at least one alphabetic character
`(?=.*[1-9])` make sure we have at least one digit
`(?=.*[۱-۹])` make sure we have at least one digit

The four conditions are mandatory.